# How to get back to an older version of my project Xcode 10

Tags: ios, file, filesystems, xcode10, undo

I have a very old project I was working on to revive it. I deleted some infoplist.strings files first, then by mistake the storyboard file. So Xcode 10 started complaining. I thought maybe I can get my deleted files back if I press Source Control -> Discard all changes. And then I lost the whole project, code and everything. All the files in the project are gone.
So please tell me there is a way to get back my files.
PS: I did close the project that went wrong. And opened it again, then there was thus, the basic files a simple project starts with.

Comment: is your project there in git or svn?

Comment: @Bappaditya sadly no :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go back to the last commit before you discarded the changes by using Xcode's source control navigator. Select the current branch from the source control navigator to see all the commits for that branch.

Select the commit you want to go back to, right-click, and choose Branch from. A sheet opens. Enter a name for the branch and click the Create button. Now you're back to the older version of the project.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I haven't used the source control navigator at all and never commited a version before :( Although I have developed this app years ago, and had 4 versions on the app store.. Yet forgot to backup the last version. So obviously there is no way I can get back to the last version, right?

Comment: Unless you have a Time Machine backup or a zip archive of the project the way it was before you started deleting files, there is no way to get back to the last version. Lesson: use version control and commit often to reduce the chances of losing important work.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using git now! Although I'm the only developer, the overhead of time and digital space spent on commits is still better than losing work :]